# Issue with imblearn: SMOTENC " TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str"'

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror, imblearn, smote

I am using SMOTENC to solve an unbalanced classification problem.

```
df_train, df_test = train_test_split(input_table_1_df, test_size=0.25, stratify=input_table_1_df["Target_Variable_SX_FASCIA_1"])
    
                  ###### SMOTE ######
    # Create features table and target table
    df_x = df_train.loc[ : , df_train.columns != "Target_Variable_SX_FASCIA_1"] 
    df_y = df_train.drop(["Target_Variable_SX_FASCIA_1"], axis=1)
    
    # From pandas to numpy arrays
    from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTENC
    
    df_X=df_x.to_numpy()
    df_Y=df_y.to_numpy()
    
    column_name_x=list(df_x.columns) 
    column_name_y=list(df_y.columns) 
    
    # Resampling
    smote_nc = SMOTENC(categorical_features=[0,1,2,3,4,5], random_state=0,sampling_strategy=.2)
    X_resampled, Y_resampled = smote_nc.fit_resample(df_X, df_Y)
    X_resampled_df= pd.DataFrame(X_resampled,columns=column_name_x)
    Y_resampled_df= pd.DataFrame(Y_resampled,columns=column_name_y)
    Training_set_Passivi_Fascia_1 = pd.concat([X_resampled_df, Y_resampled_df], axis=1)
```

I got the following error at line:

```
X_resampled, Y_resampled = smote_nc.fit_resample(df_X, df_Y)
```

**TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'**

I can understand that it is a matter of variable types, but I can not figure out how to solve this error.
I already tried to:

1. Replace all missing values
2. Fix all possible variables type misspecification

Other useful information:
The first 6 variables of the dataset are string, others are double or integer.

Just ask if you need further information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you can print head of df_x and df_y.

What I can infer from this line

```
df_y = df_train.drop(["Target_Variable_SX_FASCIA_1"], axis=1)
```

You are essentially dropping off the target variable and keeping the predictors in df_y.
My assumption is "Target_Variable_SX_FASCIA_1" is the column name of the target variable so it should be

```
df_y = df_train["Target_Variable_SX_FASCIA_1"].values
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not realize the mistake.